# Neat way to handle malloc error without checking if NULL has been returned after every single malloc call?

Tags: c

In my code almost every function has one or more malloc calls, and each time I have to do something like:

```
char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * some_int);
if (ptr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate memory.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

that's four extra lines of code and if I add them everytime after I use a malloc, the length of my code will increase a lot.. so is there an elegant way to deal with this?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: If the length of your code will increase a lot, you should think about why you're calling `malloc` so much. This probably indicates you're trying to translate a different language's idioms into C rather than using C properly...

Comment: Note that casting the return value of `malloc` in C is not needed and may hide an error the compiler would have caught without the cast.

Comment: @pmg you are talking about the `(char *)` right? What kind of errors does this cover up?

Comment: @cokedude: the error hiding happens if you do not include `<stdlib.h>` thereby using the function without a prototype. The compiler (wrongly) assumes `malloc()` returns a value of type `int` and, without the cast, complains with an error at the assignment because `int*` and `int` are not compatible. With the cast you force the compiler to shut up ... hiding the omission of the right `#include`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but there's nothing you can do about that in C. Except... *gasp... wrap it all in a macro* which will automate the `if` check and allow you to write custom error-handling code each time. There, I said it.

Seriously, C isn't meant to provide conveniences like this. If you don't mind exiting the program on the spot, you can wrap it in a function of course that does `exit` when the allocation fails -- but that's no general solution.

Comment: Or wrap it in a function instead of a macro.

Comment: @WTP: The problem with the function is that it can detect the condition, but not really handle it. At least not without your going to such great lengths that you 'd be better off with 4 lines of code at each call site. At least as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't usually much point in trying to stumble on when all memory is consumed.  Might as well call it quits:

```
char* allocCharBuffer(size_t numberOfChars) 
{
    char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * numberOfChars);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: What about some clean up procedure? Deleting temporary files... etc.

Comment: You can use `atexit()`

Answer (score 3):

You could use macros. This is cheaper than grouping this code into a function because Macros don't have the overhead a function call incurs. Macros are expanded by the preprocessor stage of compilation and can be verified by the '-E' option in gcc.
Now say we have func1(), func2(), func3()

```
#define MY_MALLOC(_ptr,_count, _lbl) \
do { \
 if (NULL == (ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * _count))) { \
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.\n"); \
    goto _lbl; \
 } \
} while(0)

func1() {  
 char *ptr;
 MY_MALLOC(ptr,10,Error);
 ....
 ...
 return (0);
Error:
 return (1);
}


func2() {  
 char *ptr;
 MY_MALLOC(ptr,10,Error);
 ....
 ...
 return (0);
Error:
 return (1);
}


func3() {  
 char *ptr;
 MY_MALLOC(ptr,10,Error);
 ....
 ...
 return (0);
Error:
 return (1);
}

#undef MY_MALLOC
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have no real error handling (except printing something and exiting), the simple and established solution is to define a function safe_malloc which incorporates the check. (Edit: Or, of course, a macro. Whatever rocks your boat.)

Answer (score 0):

If you error condition is always that simple (print error message and return) you can rewrite to save lines.

```
int errmsg(const char *msg, int retval) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    return retval;
}
```

---

```
if ((ptr = malloc(size)) == NULL) return errmsg("failed to allocate memory.", -1);
/* ... */
free(ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

C runtime should clean up any resources, including open files, buffers, and allocated data.  Even so, I like to use `int atexit( void(*)(void))` which will call registered functions upon a normal exit.  Also exit immediately if `atexit` returns a non-zero value, meaning your function was not registered.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void register_cleanup ( void ( *cleaner )( void ))
{
    if ( atexit ( cleaner ))
    {
        fprintf ( stderr, "Error, unable to register cleanup: %s\n",
                strerror ( errno )) ;
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE ) ;
    }
}
```

Then exit on malloc failure.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void *malloc_or_die ( size_t size )
{
    void *dataOut = malloc ( size ) ;
    if ( !dataOut )
    {
        fprintf ( stderr, "Error, malloc: %s\n", strerror ( errno )) ;
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE ) ;
    }
    return dataOut ;
}
void main()
{
    register_cleanup ( cleaner_fnc ) ;
    ...
    void *data = malloc_or_die ( 42 ) ;
    do_stuff ( data ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: This does not take into account other data to be deallocated within the same funtion, or not taken care of in an `atexit` function.  The macro from Anoop Menon would allow that.
If error handling is different per-function, it would be more clear to not use a macro abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define my_malloc_macro(size, ptr) do { \
    ptr = malloc(size); \
    if(!ptr) { \
        printf("malloc failed\n"); \
        return -1; \
    } \
} while(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use an extern.

Define a function in main.c:

```
 void sj_handleException(bool fatal, const char* msg, const char* libMsg){
  fprintf(stderr, msg);
  if(libMsg != NULL) fprintf(stderr, libMsg);

  if(fatal) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
}
```

Any file that mallocs memory add as you would a forward declaration:

```
extern void sj_handleException(bool fatal, const char* msg, const char* libMsg)
```

Now write malloc as:

```
char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * some_int);
if (ptr == NULL) sj_handleException(true, "failed to allocate memory.\n", NULL);
```

The linkage between the place in your code where you malloc'd memory and main.c that handles the exception is generated behind the scenes by the linker; it maps calls to the function with the function even though the two exist in different  source files.