# Ways to avoid/lessen the pain of the return value check after every single function call?

Tags: c, error-handling, return-value, conventions

In languages and/or libraries which do not support exceptions, many/almost all functions return a value indicating success or failure of their operation - the best-known example being perhaps UN*X system calls such as `open()` or `chdir()`, or some libc functions.

Anyway, when I write C code, it very often ends up looking like this:

```
int retval;
...
retval = my_function(arg1, arg2);
if (retval != SUCCESS_VALUE) { do_something(); }

retval = my_other_function(arg1, arg2);
if (retval != SUCCESS_VALUE) { do_something_else(); }
```

Now, what I would like is to just not save the retval anywhere and have errors thrown in exceptions, but I can't have that. What's the next best thing? I know that [there's no real solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462396/neat-way-to-handle-malloc-error-without-checking-if-null-has-been-returned-after), but I would still like to do *something*.

Some ideas:

- Try to live with `assert()`'s (but that's not for production code which can't afford to just die).
- Wrap function calls with a macro or a return-value-checking function, e.g. `ensure_success(my_function(args)` or `ensure_success(my_other_function(args),my_error_handler,error_handler_args)`.

Is there any other practice in this matter I might prefer?

**Edit:**

- Yes, I'm writing C code. I respect your opinion that I should try to avoid writing in C altogether, but that's really not constructive. This is not a language-wars question, please don't make it one.
- I'm not asking for opinions on what is the best thing to do, I just want additional possibilities. (I'll pick one I like, other people might pick something else.)

Comment: @sbi yes, I think we all agree that C has 'issues':)

Comment: Meanwhile, no one has joined me in my sensible vote to close this as primarily opinion-based (which preceded the language war).

Comment: In a language without exception handling, this is pretty much what you will have to do in order to not to miss an error.

Comment: @JimBalter I now did.

Comment: `assert` is not for error handling

Comment: @Jim: I didn't because it's _not_ opinion-based. (If you think that "writing such code sucks" is an opinion, you need to get educated. `:)`)

Comment: @sbi Approaches to this problem are varied and individual ... it's very much a matter of opinion how to solve it.

Comment: @Jim: Please tell me an area in programming where approaches are not varied and individual, and where it's not, to some extent, a matter of opinion which one to pick.

Comment: @sbi I'm not about to get into yet another silly debate. If you have a fact-based answer, go ahead and post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to approach this problem with a sort of scientific curiosity. There are many that claim that C's approach to error handling leads to programmers being more aware of error conditions, paying more attention to errors and where/how they should be treated. Just consider this an exercise (if a bit tedious) of awareness, like meditation :)

Don't fight it. Solve this as much as possible in the spirit of C and your view of things will expand slightly.

Check out this article on C error handling mantra: http://tratt.net/laurie/tech_articles/articles/how_can_c_programs_be_so_reliable

One general answer to your general question is: try to make functions as small as possible so that you can directly return from them on errors. This approach is good in all languages. The rest is an exercise in structuring code.

Comment: Lemme cite you the article you posted: *(...)one has to handle all possible error paths oneself. This is extremely painful(...)*

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz No pain, no gain: http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/memory-medic/201106/learning-no-pain-no-gain

Comment: To be clear, I agree with the conclusion of the article: "I don't recommend using C unless much thought has been given to the decision". I would like to add: C doesn't produce reliable software, it produces reliable programmers.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz That is, indeed, the alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You are facing the fact that in many solutions to problems lots of things can go wrong.

Handling this "error"-situations is part of the solution to the problem.

So my answer is either stick to solve issues where nothing (or few) can fail, or take the burden of accepting that handling error conditions *is part of the solution*.

So (also) designing/writing the code necessary to handle failures is an essential way to success.

---

As for practical advise: Seeing error handling as part of the code in whole, for error handling the same rules apply as to each and every other line of code:

- easy to understand
- strict enough to be efficient
- flexible enough to get extended
- fail save (redundant to mention in this context)
- systematic/consistent (in terms of patterns, naming, layout)
- documented

Possible language constructs to use:

- `break`s out of local contexts
- (`goto`)*
- (`longjmp` & friends to "simulate" exceptions)*
- cleanly defined (again systematic/consistent) function declarations and return codes

---

* To be used with discipline in a structured way.

Comment: Using longjmp is asking for trouble.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus If you call yourself a Master you shall be able to handle this... - but you are right, I do not like to use it. Too stressy. But I couldn't resist to mention it, having listened your war above ... ;-)

Comment: `longjmp` and `goto` could be used, if it's a mature and disciplined coder .. ;-)

Comment: @alk Even manual page of `longjmp` says it's bad and should be avoided. Maturity of coder has *absolutely nothing* to do with the fact the whole idea behind it is bad.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I disagree - `longjmp()` fills the void between status codes/`errno` and `exit()`/`abort()`, and becomes particularly useful if callbacks are involved

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to achieve better error handling. It all depends on what you are trying to do. To implement extensive error handling routines just to call a few functions isn't going to be worth the fuss. In larger code bases, you can consider it.

Better error handling is most often achieved by adding more abstraction layers. For example, if you have these functions

```
int func1 (int arg1, int arg2)
{
  return arg1 == arg2;
}

int func12 (int arg1, int arg2)
{
  return arg1 - arg2;
}
```

and some error handler function:

```
void err_handler_func1 (int err_code)
{
  if(err_code != 0)
  {
    halt_and_catch_fire();
  }
}
```

then you could group functions and error handlers together. Either by making a struct based data type containing one function and one error handler, and then make an array of such structs. Or by making individual, related arrays accessed with an index:

```
typedef void(*func_t)(int, int);
typedef void(*err_handler_t)(int);

typedef enum
{
  FUNC1,
  FUNC2,
  ...
  FUNC_N // not a function name, but the number of items in the enum
} func_name_t;

const func_t function [FUNC_N] =
{
  func1,
  func2,
  ...
};

const err_handler_t err_handler [FUNC_N] = 
{
  err_handler_func,
  err_handler_func,
  ...
}
```

once you have this, you can make wrap the function calls in a suitable abstraction layer:

```
void execute_function (int func_n, int arg1, int arg2)
{
  err_handler[func_n]( function[func_n](arg1, arg2 );
}

execute_function (FUNC1, 1, 2);
execute_function (FUNC2, 2, 2);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

As with a lot of things, error handling in C requires more care than in other (higher-level) languages.

Personally, I do not believe that's necessarily a bad thing as it forces you to actually think about error conditions, the associated cotrol flow and you'll need to come up with a proper design (because if you don't, the result will probably be an unmaintainable mess).

Roughly, you can divide error conditions into fatal and non-fatal ones.

Of the non-fatal ones, there are those that are recoverable, ie you just try again or use a fallback mechanism. Those, you normally handle inline, even in languages that support exceptions.

Then, there are the ones you cannot recover from. Instead, you might want to log the failure, but in genereal just notify the caller, eg via a return code or some `errno` type variable. Possibly, you might need to do some cleanup within the function, where a `goto` might help to structure the code more cleanly.

Of the fatal ones, there are those that terminate the program, ie you just print some error message and `exit()` with non-zero status.

Then, there are the exceptional cases, where you just dump core (eg via `abort()`). Assertion failures are a subset of those, but you only should use `assert()` if the situation is supposed to be impossible during normal execution so your code still fails cleanly on `NDEBUG` builds.

A third class of fatal exceptions is those that do not terminate the whole program, but just a (possibly deeply nested) call chain. You can use `longjmp()` here, but you must take care to properly clean up resources like allocated memory or file descriptors, which means you need to keep track of these resources in some pools.

A bit of variadic macro magic makes it possible to come up with nice syntax for at least some of these cases, eg

```
_Bool do_stuff(int i);
do_stuff(i) || panic("failed to do stuff with %i", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

In rare but happy situations you can exploit the short-circuiting nature of `&&` and `||`:

```
if (my_function1(arg1, arg2) == SUCCESS_VALUE 
 && my_function2(arg3) == SUCCESS_VALUE)
{
  /* Proceed */
}
else
{
  /* Cry and die. */
}
```

If you must differentiate between an error in function 1 and 2, this might not work so well.

Aesthetically, not super-beautiful but this is error handling after all :)

Comment: Ok, that's an option, but I try to avoid putting the call within an if statement; I find that has a somewhat obfuscating effect.

Comment: Alas, that excludes a lot of possibilities. You could macroify it though.

Also, I will get shot for this comment, but sometimes `goto` helps too.

Comment: No one should object to you're mentioning goto ... it's a modern feature of modern structured assembly languages like C.

Comment: So, can you expand your answer to suggest a `goto`-based approach?

Comment: @DeadMG You may have missed a previous (mod-deleted) discussion here.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the glib APIs have a [`GError`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Error-Reporting.html) abstraction which acts as kind of (explicit of course, this being C) exception container. Or maybe `errno` abstraction is a better description.

It's used as a pointer to pointer, allowing you to quickly check if a call succeeded (a new GError will be created to hold any error) *and* handle detailed error information at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses my question... unless you're suggesting I write wrappers with this kind of exception holder?

Answer (score 0):

If there was a solution to this in C, then exceptions would not have been invented. You only have two choices:

- Move to a language that supports exceptions.
- Cry about whatever factors forced you to use C and write C, with all it's unfixable problems.

Although, if you're using Visual C, you can use SEH as exceptions in C. It's not pretty but does work.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of it, but Go has a disciplined approach to this problem that isn't based on exceptions (except for some very restricted forms of it).